# How to check the output datum reference in V2

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

The following code would work for V1:
outputDatum :: EkivalEscrowDatum

```
outputDatum = case transferDatum $ txOutDatumHash ownOutput >>= flip findDatum info of

    Nothing -> traceError "Transfer output datum not found"

    Just d  -> d
```

However, "txOutDatumHash" seems to be missing a corresponding implementation in V2.
I understand we may face inline Datum, which would not include the Hash, but backward compatibility appears to not be fully implemented on this function.
From the plutus-apps examples, I noticed a mixture of V1 modules whenever the datum was being verified.
PS: transferDatum :: Maybe Datum -> Maybe EkivalEscrowDatum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plutus v2 you have to differentiate since inline datums could be present at a given output.

```
outputDatumByHash :: DatumHash -> Maybe Datum
outputDatumByHash h = findDatum h info

ownOutputDatum :: TxOut -> Maybe TransferDatum
ownOutputDatum TxOut{txOutDatum=OutputDatumHash h} = transferDatum $ outputDatumByHash h
ownOutputDatum _                                   = Nothing

outputDatum :: TxOut -> TransferDatum
outputDatum txOut = case ownOutputDatum txOut of
    Nothing -> traceError "Transfer output datum not found"
    Just d  -> d
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API:

V1's `TxOut` uses `txOutDatumHash :: Maybe DatumHash`

V2's `TxOut` uses `txOutDatum :: OutputDatum`
where `data OutputDatum = NoOutputDatum | OutputDatumHash DatumHash | OutputDatum Datum`

So V2 still has DatumHash but you need to also handle the possibility of OutputDatum (inline datum).